# Any way to simplify the following sed?

Tags: sed

Is there a way to simplify the following `sed` (not using another binary, only sed), bearing in mind the requirement to re-order the numerical blocks?

```
echo "server16 :: FetchChannels.20160131.170019.875685.16232510.22" |
sed -e 's/\ \:\:\ \([a-zA-Z]*\)\.\([0-9]\{4\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\.\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)/\ \ \5\:\6\:\7\ \4\/\3\/\2\ \ \1/g' \
    -e 's/\..*//g'
```

Sample output:

```
server16  17:00:19 31/01/2016  FetchChannels
```

Comment: You would arguably do better using the ISO 8601 date format for the output such as `2016-01-31 17:00:19` — it will be easier to sort, etc, and is culturally neutral (or 'foreign' to everyone).

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "server16 :: FetchChannels.20160131.170019.875685.16232510.22" | \
sed -re 's| :: ([a-zA-Z]*)\.([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2}).*|  \5:\6:\7 \4/\3/\2  \1|'
```

- Use `-Ee` instead on Mac OS X
- Adding `-r` (or -E on OSX) in order to remove some `\`.
- Changing `/` to `|` so `/` doesn't need to be escaped

Comment: Nice job.  Only the C shell requires a backslash after a pipe symbol; real shells don't.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/(.*)::(.*)\.(....)(..)(..)\.(..)(..)(..).*/\1\6:\7:\8 \5\/\4\/\3\2/' file
```

The matching `::` and `.`'s will most likely make it a unique match.

Or if you prefer:

```
sed 's/\(.*\)::\(.*\)\.\(....\)\(..\)\(..\)\.\(..\)\(..\)\(..\).*/\1\6:\7:\8 \5\/\4\/\3\2/' file
```